# How to transform text file to array

Tags: python, text

I have text file:

```
   sn   we
   200  8.8
   99.3 10
```

I tried

```
np.genfromtxt(b[], delimiter=' ', dtype=None)
```

I want to get numpay array or pandas data frame with 2 columns (This is coordinates). What is the easiest way to do it? Delimiter - tab.

Comment: Magic. Thank you. I can not add you score, butthank thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a dataframe, call `read_csv` with `delim_whitespace=True`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delim_whitespace=True)
```

Alternatively, specify a regex-based separator:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\s+')
```

You *also* can retrieve a `numpy` array of values by querying `df.values`. Otherwise, you can directly retrieve a `numpy` array using `np.loadtxt`:

```
array = np.loadtxt('file.txt', skiprows=1)
```